# How to locate Android mount points?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, external-sd, mount

It all started with an intent to install Link2SD to my in-car Android audio system. Repartitioned SD card into FAT32 + Ext2, but something went wrong ("Mount script cannot created" by Link2SD, etc.). So I've done some research and eventually messed something up and now I've got 2 partitions mounted into the same directory!
My SD is `/dev/block/mmcblk1` with `/dev/block/mmcblk1p1` for FAT32 partition and `/dev/block/mmcblk1p2` for Ext2.
`mount` says both partitions are mounted to the same `/sdcard/external_sd` location.
I was trying to locate a place where these 2 mountpoints are coming from but with no success. I know there's no `/etc/fstab` at Android, but `/etc/vold.fstab` has nothing about `mmcblk1` or `/sdcard/external_sd`. I've looked through all `init.*.rc` scripts in root but found nothing either.

So where is a place that mounts those 2 partitions??? I've got no more thoughts left except for `grep -nwr / -e external_sd`, but it takes forever to complete and it's not that easy to surf results with touchscreen only...

The system is HiCES: Android 4.0.something with LOTS of stuff on top; quite buggy and unstable - not sure that anyone has experienced same problems on the same system :)